How to get a specific date and time format in Java 11?
I'm working on a Spring Boot project and I need to get the current date and time in a specific format, but I can't find that specific pattern.
This is the format: "2024-11-03 11:12:28.000"
I know how to get the current date and time, I don't know that pattern. Can somebody help me with the pattern for that format? Thank you!

[Edit] your question and post the code you use to get the current date and time. Then I can tell you how to convert that to a string with your desired format.

I believe your answer is here. Or with more depth here.

... but I can't find that specific pattern. Wonder where you searched?? The patterns are all described here.

Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

The linked original question is 15 years old, so beware of many outdated answers. Use the answers that use java.time, the modern Java date and time API ad its DateTimeFormatter. Also prefer ZonedDateTime for the date and time in your time zone. The SimpleDateFormat class used in many of the answers was a notorious troublemaker of a class and has been outdated for 10 years.

Looks like yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS to me. What's the problem?
You should be using JDK 22. JDK 11 is long past its support life. Yes, the difference matters. Upgrade now.
The latest version of Spring Boot is 3.2.4. I'm betting you should upgrade that, too.

Agree w/ HH.  I see no difference in behavior between 'yyyy' and 'uuuu'.  Never used it.  Can you explain?

@duffymo See: uuuu versus yyyy in DateTimeFormatter formatting pattern codes in Java?

Never, ever knew it until today.  Thank you!
